# Loading of a resource blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: express, content-security-policy

I'm getting the error below in the console of my browser:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at `http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico` (“default-src”).

I searched online and saw that this should be fixed with the snippet of code below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    img-src * 'self' data: https: http:;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

I added this to my front-end `app.component.html` file (the parent template for all my front-end views), but this didn't work as expected.

I've also tried multiple permutations thereupon to no avail.

My front-end is at `localhost:4200` and back-end at `localhost:3000`.

Below is the snippet of code from my back-end server (middleware):

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*',cors());
var allowCrossDomain = function(req,res,next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

I also have now added the following middleware to my backend (Express) server:

```
const csp = require('express-csp-header');

app.use(csp({
  policies: {
      'default-src': [csp.SELF, 'http://localhost:3000/', 'http://localhost:4200/' ],
      'script-src': [csp.SELF, csp.INLINE],
      'style-src': [csp.SELF],
      'img-src': ['data:', 'favico.ico'],
      'worker-src': [csp.NONE],
      'block-all-mixed-content': true
  }
}));
```

. . . but still hasn't fixed the problem.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have the serve your resources also over https. One file can break the whole chain.

Comment: Where is the original CSP being set (presumably the server, in a header)? If you're simply trying to debug your policy and added all those extra allow lines, that's ok, but if that's what you plan to put in production, you might as well just remove the CSP altogether. You should understand what the CSP's purpose is in order to configure it properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Content Security Policy (CSP) is a mechanism to help prevent Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and is best handled at server side; please note it can be handled at client side as well, making use of the `<meta>` tag element of your HTML.

When configured and enabled, a web server will return the appropriate `Content-Security-Policy` in the HTTP response header.

You may want to read more about CSP on the on the HTML5Rocks website and Mozilla developer page [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

[Google CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) is a handy and free online tool to help test CSP for your website or web application.

In your instance, you may need to add the line below without enforcing HTTPS as protocol using the `https:` directive;
*Because your website or application (as shared) is not available over HTTPS.*

```js
res.header('Content-Security-Policy', "img-src 'self'");
```

Starting with `default-src` directive set to `none` is a great way to start deploying your CSP settings.

In case you opt to use the [Content-Security-Policy middleware for Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csp-header)
, you may get started as illustrated in the snippet below;

```js
const csp = require('express-csp-header');
app.use(csp({
    policies: {
        'default-src': [csp.NONE],
        'img-src': [csp.SELF],
    }
}));

// HTTP response header will be defined as:
// "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self';"
```

Remember CSP are case or application specific and based on your project requirements.

As such, you need to fine tune in order to meet your need.

Comment: Many thanks. I set `default-src` to `none` on both front- and back- end, but that still didn't fix the problem. Any other ideas? Tks!

Comment: @Crowdpleasr: Did you set `img-src` to `self`? Please do and share a screenshot of your console browser should you still have a challenge.

Comment: Thank you. I set `img-src` to `self` on both front and back end, and also added a screenshot of console browser. Many thanks again for all your help!

Comment: The crazy thing is that the app was working fine for several days. Then I added a `POST` route to back-end today, and now I suddenly have this CSP problem which I can't get rid of.

Comment: Do remember to keep your code clean and free of bloat; there's no need implementing CSP everywhere. Server-side, in your HTTP response header is the most effective option.

Comment: OK, got it. Please note I never added any CSP anywhere. I only started toying with CSP after I started getting those "errors".

Comment: You should check your code for the culprit script, or possibly a browser extension.

Comment: Very strange! The "challenge" is over `favicon.ico`, and I searched my entire codebase, and the only instance of `favicon.ico` is in the `index.html` file (front-end, which is at `localhost:4200`). So I eliminated the favicon.ico html `href` so no favicon.ico left in the codebase, but two strange things: FIRSTLY, I'm still getting the "challenge" even with `favicon.ico` gone, and SECONDLY the challenge references `*localhost:3000*/favicon.ico`, but `favicon.ico` was on the `*localhost:4200*` client side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194205/discussion-between-nyedidikeke-and-crowdpleasr).

Comment: As @nyedidikeke suggested, getting rid of CSP on client-side solved the issue!

Comment: @Crowdpleasr. I'm facing the same issues. But none of the above answers helped. I even removed `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` from my `index.html` but still same error. Please help me.

Comment: @Tanzeel [Let's continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200465/tanzeel).

Comment: Continuing the discussion in chat does not help the rest of us who are trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Newer is directives instead of policies.

Answer (score 3):

- /favicon.ico is automatically loaded by the web browser in the absence of other URLs for the favicon. This is specified by:
  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#rel-icon
- You current Content-Security-Policy was blocking it. You need to use something like: `Content-Security-Policy: img-src 'self'`

---

Ideally web browser shouldn't even try /favicon.ico when it would be blocked. After all, loading /favicon.ico is triggered by the web browser, not the developer.
I patched chrome (version >= 88) to remove the error:

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2438388

---

Answer (score 1):

If you have a strict CSP header for e.g. images and other static files like

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none';
```

then Firefox will assume that it also means that the *implicit* reference to `/favicon.ico` used for tab icon is also banned. Chrome has internal special case where the implicit `/favicon.ico` is always allowed no matter the CSP header. To grant Firefox access to implicit `/favicon.ico` you have to add `img-src 'self'` at minimum.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self';
```

Also note that the *syntax* of `Content-Security-Policy` policy only supports allowing specific origins and not URLs. The original question had `img-src ... favicon.ico` where it should have just said `img-src ... 'self'`. (CSP version 2 has limited support for prefix path within an origin but it has pretty complex edge cases with redirects so you should avoid using that feature if possible at all.)

Comment: I've reported this issue to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1735994

Answer (score 0):

nyedidikeke's answer is awesome !

With `express-csp-header` middleware, set the `policies` to pass CSP.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-csp-header

Here is my ndoejs code :

```
const { expressCspHeader, INLINE, NONE, SELF } = require('express-csp-header');
const app = express();
// other app.use() options ...
app.use(expressCspHeader({ 
    policies: { 
        'default-src': [expressCspHeader.NONE], 
        'img-src': [expressCspHeader.SELF], 
    } 
}));
```

enjoy !!