# Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource -CSP

Tags: express, firefox, content-security-policy

I've been stuck on this problem in my express app for ages now, and it doesn't seem to budge. This CSP error has been always the same and not going away. I'm using Firefox on Linux Ubuntu 22.04. [image]

This is what I tried to do but it didn't help:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();


app.get('/ping', (_req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
  res.send('pong');
});


const PORT = 3003;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried extensions and changing settings from about:config but didn't help at all. Can someone explain why this error is persisting?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67827527/21972629) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips to sort out this,

**Adjust CSP Rules:**

Based on the specific CSP violation reports, you may need to adjust your CSP rules to allow certain resources or domains to be loaded. For example, if your app loads resources from external domains or uses scripts from CDNs, you should adjust your CSP rules accordingly.

Example:

```
res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self' https://example.com");
```

or

**Use a Report-Only Header:**

During development and debugging, you can use the "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" header instead of "Content-Security-Policy." This header will report CSP violations to the browser console without blocking content. It's a helpful tool for fine-tuning your CSP rules.

Example:

```
res.set("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'");
```

Other things to check:

**Check Dependencies:**

If your app relies on third-party libraries or scripts, ensure that they are compatible with your CSP rules. Some libraries may dynamically load resources that could trigger CSP violations.

**Ensure Secure Origins:**

Make sure that your app and all its dependencies are served over HTTPS. CSP rules can be more restrictive in insecure (HTTP) contexts.

Hope you find helpful!

Comment: I added the specific URL that i wanted accessible after default-src, yet nothing really changed, still get "Cannot GET/" rendered. Everyone seems to find a solution im thinking could there be something wrong with my browser.